# Does static variables in web applications lead to memory leak (and OutOfMemory in perspective)?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Static variables are garbage collected in such manner:

> static variables are referenced by the Class objects which are referenced by ClassLoaders. So, Static variables are only garbage collected when the class loader which has loaded the class in which static field is there is garbage collected in java.

So suppose a web application and Tomcat managing it. There are static variables at a particular application which is actively redeployed multiple times.

Are the static variables remain in metaspace since the classloader hasn't been GCed while redeploying?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is: obviously a class can't be "garbage collected" while it is in use.

But then things become implementation specific: when tomcat redeploys an application, that is done by throwing out an existing class loader. It would be logical that tomcat does all it can do to absolutely "forget" about that old class loader, and the classes loaded by it!

So when that class loaders becomes garbage, all things loaded by it become garbage, eligible for collection, too.

And quoting their [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions):

> WebappX — A class loader is created for each web application that is deployed in a single Tomcat instance. All unpacked classes and resources in the /WEB-INF/classes directory of your web application, plus classes and resources in JAR files under the /WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application, are made visible to this web application, but not to other ones.

But then it turns out, the whole discussion is a bit more complicated, I suggest you start reading [here](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rjc201/) and [there](https://dzone.com/articles/reloading-java-classes-301).

In essence, the story goes like this: re-deploying an application results in throwing away its class loader, and creation of a new one. But it is still possible to create memory leaks here.

Comment: are you sure Tomcat doesn't use the same class loader to load multiple web applications? (i've no idea BTW...)

Comment: sure, i'm convinced it's ok in Tomcat too. But I was recently asked at the interview if i'm using static variables at web apps and whether I ever got OutOfMemory errors while multiple redeploying LOL. I said NO ))) but i'm interested now...

Comment: You linked to [Reloading Java Classes 201: How do ClassLoader leaks happen?](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rjc201/). That article did an excellent job of explaining the problem, but it was written over 8 years ago. Do you know whether the explanation given remains valid? I guess I can find out for myself by running the code, but I thought I'd take the lazy option first...

Comment: @skomisa I know. You see, it is not like this answer is getting a lot of views, or upvotes. I saw that this article is pretty old, but a quick search didn't reveal much newer information. As said: this is pretty established technology, not in the hype any more. People just use it, it works, and no more big discussions ...